# How to generate DDL scripts from tables in Oracle NoSql?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I have some tables with huge columns (more than `600 columns`) and don't have `DDL`(create table) scripts for it. I can create the script by seeing the table schema using `DESCRIBE` keyword in oracle nosql, but it's a huge pain in the back because of manual operation.

Is there any way to generate `DDL` scripts for existing tables in `Oracle NoSql` database?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this at this time. It's being considered as an extension to the sql shell. One option in user code would be to use the "describe as json ..." call and parse the JSON description of the table to construct the DDL string